# HashMap to store user accounts and transactions

Tags: java, hashmap

I wonder if it is possible to store two sets of data in the same HashMap like:

`{key:string, account:object, transactions: { timestamp:datetime, type:byte, amount:int}`.

If yes, would you suggest how to achieve such model. If not, are there any alternatives without using third-party libraries.

Say we have an object - account. Each account have transactions. The goal is to be able to add transactions to accounts and display them later.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the title and terms are incorrect, so please, do suggest your edition of the question.

Comment: Why use a `HashMap`? Just define to data types with the appropriate members.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, could you elaborate?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to declare the appropiate classes to store the data you need. For example, the transactions:

```
public class Transaction {
    private Date timestamp;
    private byte type; // I prefer to use an enum here...
    private int amount;
    .... // next add the getter and setter for each attribute
}
```

Then, you can declare the class to contain the account data. For example:

```
public class Account {
    .... // declare the fields of the account, for example, name, address, ...
    private  List<Transaction> transactions;
    .... // next add the getter and setter for each attribute
}
```

Finally, you can declare and populate the HashMap with all the data.

```
// first create the HashMap
HashMap<String, Account> accounts = new HashMap<String, Account>();

// then populate the HashMap with accounts
Account a = ...;
String key = ....;
accounts.put(key, a);
```

Comment: I understand this. But how would you store accounts and transactions in the same list? I mean, how would you work with transactions if when HashMap returns Account as values().

Comment: You could access the transactions of an account, simply by using a getter method in the account. For example: accounts.get(key).getTransactions()

Comment: the only problem is displaying transactions as all transactions for all accounts are displayed at the same time, regardless of the key in HashMap. Like if there was one List for all accounts.

Comment: When you construct an Account, you need to set an unique list with only the transactions of that account. That way, you are creating a HashMap with the hierarchy that you need to display: key -> account -> transactions of the account

Comment: This is exactly what I attempted to do by placing transactions list into account class. But it seems to not work that way.

Comment: The problem, I think, is that you need to create a NEW list for every account, and put in that list ONLY the transactions of that account (and don't add any other transaction). Maybe if you put the code that you use to build the HashMap, Accounts and Transactions, I can understand better the real problem.

Comment: I think I found the problem. An your answer was definetly the right one!

Comment: I'm glad that you solved you problem. Good luck with your code.

Comment: Thank you for your help pal!

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you could achieve that by making an  HashMap, and check the class of retrieved objects. It's an error prone and code heavy approach though and I'd recommend strongly against it in the design, there's probably a better way to achieve your goal, if you share what that goal is.

If you're committed to this path though, you could handle the retrieval using either getClass().getName(), or by catching ClassCastExceptions:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put( "key", "string" );
map.put( account, object );
map.put( "transactions", transactionsMap );


Object string = map.get("key" );
String type = string.getClass().getName();
if( "java.lang.String".equals( type ) ) {
    System.out.println( "Retrieved "+string+" for key" );
}
Object account = new Object();

Object object = map.get( account );
System.out.println( "Retrieved "+object+" for account "+account );

Object transactionsObj = map.get( "transactions" );
try {
    Map transactions = (Map)transactionsObj;
    System.out.println( "Retrieved "+transactions+" for transactions" );
} catch( ClassCastException e ) {
    System.out.println( "Transactions was not a map "+e.getMessage() );
}
```

Comment: The goal is to be able to create accounts, add transactions and show those transactions in console.

Comment: Why do you need to put them into a single Map? Could you split them into two Maps, one for accounts and one for transactions? That'd mean you could use a generic to make it type safe. Or if the transactions belong to an account, then Alejandro Goñi's answer above is a superior solution. If you need to be able to extract all Transactions at once, then create a separate List that holds the transactions.

Comment: I don't really HAVE to, I am just learning Java and experimenting to see what would be the most efficient way of achieving structure similar to what I described. I just fin this structure to be very comfortable to use.

Comment: That's fair enough... Alejandro's solution seems a better fit then, using generics with Collections and POJOs. Be careful about synchronisation if the data is being shared amongst different threads, you may wish to wrap the collections in a Synchronised version to help protect it.

Comment: his version is great, but when I am displaying the transactions they are displaying as if there was one list for all accounts.

Comment: Is that the desired behaviour or the actual?